# How to create hardware kill switch for wireless lan?

Tags: laptop, security

[Purism laptop](https://www.crowdsupply.com/purism/librem-laptop/thank-you-and-more-hardware-options) should have a hardware kill switch for wireless connections.

> "Bundling all RF, including Wireless and Bluetooth, into a single kill switch, possibly located near the right side edge (image provided for design reference). This will physically cut power to the Wireless (and Bluetooth) card."

How this is possible since wifi is usually implemented by a mini PCI express add-on card which is attached directly to the motherboard?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the topology of a motherboard. If they provide for that function, it will be there.

From the description of the project this is (probably) exactly what they want to do.

There are also other ways to do that - for example extra media board connected to motherboard via ribbon cable - but the more you can squeeze on the motherboard, the cheaper the system usually is.